# Login failed for user "domainname\\username" error in asp.net

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, windows-authentication

I am getting following error at connection open step

```
if (con != null && con.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                    con.Open(); //getting error here
```

Message: Login failed for user "domainname\username"

Number: 18456

Then I check solution at [Click here](https://bjtechnews.org/2012/03/20/microsoft-sql-server-error-18456-login-failed-for-user/) and found that already SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode is selected then what would the problem.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

In connectionString Integrated Security value was True. I set it to False. It's working now.